# Guillemin and Pollack, Exercise 4.8.7, understanding the hint.

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

I have copied below exercise 4.8.7 from Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*
[image]

I'm having trouble following the last part of the hint (Exercise 7 of Section 6 refers to the fact that homotopic maps induce the same map on cohomology).

Following the hint, we pick a form $\theta \in \Omega^k(X)$ and an open cover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ where $U_i$ is smoothly isotoptic to a coordinate neighbourhood we started with $U$. Then we choose a partition of unity subordinate to this cover i.e. we have smooth functions $\rho_i$'s with $\mathrm{supp}(\rho_i) \subset U_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\rho_i \equiv 1$. Letting $\theta_i = \rho_i\theta$, we have forms supported in $U_i$ such that they add upto to $\theta$. Okay, now, since $U_i$ is smooth isotopic to $U$, we have a isomorphism of cohomology groups $H^k(U_i) \cong H^i(U)$, so $[\theta_i]$ corresponds to some class of a scalar multiple of $[\omega]$. But the hint is saying that we make it so that $\theta_i$ is cohomologous to a scalar multiple of $\omega$, that makes me think I'm not using the fact that $U_i$ and $U$ are isotopic well enough. I suppose I'm also confused on how're we intepreting isotopy in this context.

Any comments will be helpful. I know I'm asking for help in the middle a chain of thought that you may not be privy to, so apologies for that!

Update: After following the comments, we have the following. Let $h_{i,t}$ denote the isotopy between $U$ and $U_i$, then for $h_{i,1}^*\theta_i$, as a compactly supported form on $U$, we have $[h_{i,1}^*\theta_i] = c_i[\omega]$, where $c_i = \int_Uh_{i,1}^*\theta_i = \int_{U_i}\theta_i$, since $h_{i,1}^*$ is a diffeomorphism (this comes from the initial hint and 4.8.6).

Then I suppose letting $H_i$ denote the inverse of $h_{i,1}$, we have $[\theta_i] = c_i[H_i^*\omega]$ and so $[\theta] = \sum_{i=1}^nc_i[H_i^*\omega]$.

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense, actually, since $\theta_i$ is a form on $U_i$ and $\omega$ is a form on $U$. So you need to use the isotopy to pull $\theta_i$ back to a form on $U$, and the fact that you have an isotopy will tell you that integrals are preserved.

Comment: I'm not sure which part doesn't make sense, I haven't used or claimed that $\theta_i$ is a form on $U$, I used the word corresponds to indicate I'm using the isomorphism.

Comment: Right, I see that we can pull forms to $U$ but I'm confused on how to use that to conclude that $\theta$ is in fact cohomologous to a scalar multiple of $\omega$. My other question is: why isotopy? Doesn't homotopy suffice?

Comment: Being cohomologous isn't good enough, by the way, since we're talking about forms on open sets. I should have remarked that the first time. Homotopy is too weak. How do you know homotopic maps preserve integrals (again on non-compact creatures)?

Comment: Let $h_t$ be the isotopy, then $[h_t^*\theta_i] = [c\omega]$, where $c = \int_U h_t^*\theta_i = \int_{U_i}\theta_i$. I suppose my question then is how to use this to write $[\theta] = [k\omega]$, where presumably $k = \sum_{i=1}^n\int_{U_i}\theta_i$

Comment: Not $h_t$, but $h_1$. You have to use the isotopies to glue together the coboundary information explicitly.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm not sure I see how to do that though. Can you give a leading hint in that direction?

Comment: I'm going to let you edit your question indicating the progress we've made ... As a hint to your last question, it's at this stage you really will need to know you have an isotopy and use the diffeomorphism $h_1$.

Comment: Wrote an update, I think this was what you were alluding to. Unsure how to move forward, the essential problem is - how to obtain only $\omega$.

Comment: Write down the explicit coboundaries, as I already said. $H_i^*\omega - \omega = d\eta_i$.

Comment: I think I get my missing piece, we're using the Isotpy lemma implicitly and assuming our map $h_1$ is isotopic to the identity i.e. $h_0 = \mathrm{id}$. I took the existence of this cover as a black box without wondering where it came from. Thank, I think have it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this problem is how we construct this cover given in the hint, which I initially took as a black box. We started with a $U$, let's fix a $p\in U$. Then for any $x\in X$, by the Isotopy lemma, we can find a diffeomorphism $h_x:X \to X$ which is isotopic to the identity on $X$ such that $h_x(p) = x$. Then $\{h_x(U)\}_{x\in X}$ is an open cover of a compact manifold, so we can choose a finite subcover, say $\{h_1(U),\ldots,h_N(U)\}$. Then $U_i = h_i(U)$ is the cover given in the hint. Since $h_i \sim \mathrm{id}_X$, then $h_i^\sharp = \mathrm{id}_X^\sharp$ (pullback maps on cohomology), and things follow. I won't bother fixing notation in my question and the update I added. But everything comes together to give us a solution. (I refer to and use notations from Guillemin-Pollack.)